# “I have a (gerund)” other than desires and wishes

Tags: nouns, gerunds

Someone I know is trying to understand the phrase “I have a craving”.

We know the meaning of “craving” - it’s a strong desire, especially for food or drink. And I can think of another word that can be used the same way - “longing”, such as “we have a longing”.

But is “craving” being used as a noun or a gerund, and can you “have” a gerund other than a desire or a wish?

I guess you can “have” a feeling or “have” a hearing, but “feeling” and “hearing” are pretty different from “feel” and “hear”.

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary? None of the "-ing" words you mentioned are gerunds

Comment: It's a noun (aka gerundial noun): note the articles which are used with nouns, but never with verbs. It can also take adjectival premodification, as in "I have an occasional craving".

Comment: You can *have a **liking*** or ***feeling** [for something]*, but I don't think you can normally have a ***hearing***. You can certainly *have a **listen** [to a song]* though. And you can *have a feel* (BrE slang ***cop** a feel*) in sexualised contexts - not the same as having a feeling..

Comment: "Hearing" can be a noun in the right context, e.g. The judge said that he had a hearing the next day".